# Delphi editor. Cursor style

Tags: delphi, colors, editor, mouse-cursor

I changed Delphi editor background color to dark-grey. Sorry, I cannot post image because I have not some reputation on this forum.

But this color hides mouse cursor. How to change cursor style\color in editor window?
I cannot find any cursor options in Delphi IDE settings.

Answer (score 3):

There are no cursor settings in the IDE because the IDE uses the system cursors. The system cursors can be changed from the control panel. You might consider whether or not the background colour of an IDE should be driving your system cursor choice.

Comment: I am too have my background as black so the cursor is not visible enough is there any tool to change cursor color ?